# Coloring a Cluster. Kmeans

Tags: python-3.x, k-means

I currently have the code below:

I have also imported the libraries numpy and matplotlib.

```
def colorTheCluster(data,centroidCoordinates):
index = AssignPointsToCluster(data,centroidCoordinates) #index contains an 1d array of size 1000 of values [0 1 2 1 3 0....]
indexList = list(index) # i wanted to make it into a list so i can use a for loop
colorMap = {0:'r', 1 : 'b', 2:"y", 3: 'p', 4 :'g'} 
for num in indexList: #[0,1,1,2,3,0,0...]
    for keys in colorMap.keys(): #{1, 2, 0 , 4}
        if keys == num:
            plt.scatter(data[:,0], data[:,1], marker = '+', c = colorMap[0])
        elif keys == num:
            plt.scatter(data[:,0], data[:,1], marker = '+', c = colorMap[1])
        elif keys == num:    
            plt.scatter(data[:,0], data[:,1], marker = '+', c = colorMap[2])
        elif keys == num:
            plt.scatter(data[:,0], data[:,1], marker = '+', c = colorMap[3])
        elif keys == num:
            plt.scatter(data[:,0], data[:,1], marker = '+', c = colorMap[4])
return plt.show()

print(colorTheCluster(data(), centroidCoordinates()))
```

`data()` is a function that contains an array of 1000 x 2

`centroidCoordinates()` is an array of m x2 ( in this case i used m = 4)

I want every point in the cluster which is assigned an index to change color accordingly but doesnt seem to work.

Comment: For clarification, it seems `data` is probably an array, not a function.

Answer (score 0):

The `plt.scatter` function accepts a parameter `c` – this can be a list/array of the same length as your data.

```
# make some fake data
data = np.random.random([1000,2])
index = np.random.choice([0,1,2,3], size=len(data))

# scatter plot the data, using `index` to indicate color
plt.scatter(data[:,0], data[:,1], c=index)
# or alternatively:
plt.scatter(*data.T, c=index)
```

To define specific colors, you want to make a colormap:

```
import matplotlib.colors as mcols

# define a colormap using a list of custom colors
cmap = mcols.ListedColormap(['r','b','y','purple','g'])

# scatter plot the data using your new colormap
plt.scatter(*data.T, c=index, cmap=cmap)
```

Note that I replaced `'p'`, which is not a color code matplotlib understands, with `'purple'`, which is.